# MvvmCross overriding viewmodel associations for Android

Tags: android, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am trying to override the default view model association but having no luck so far.  I need to override this default behavior because some of my ViewModels do not follow the name convention assumed by the default view model lookup.  For example, I have some ViewModels in namespace Pidac.Core.ViewModels, while the Views are defined in MyApplication.Droid.Views.

I have tried the option to provide an explicity type mapping in Setup.cs of the Droid project as follows:

```
 protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
        {
            var viewModelViewLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
            {
                  { typeof (FirstViewModel), typeof(FirstView) },     
                  { typeof (FloatSettingViewModel), typeof(FloatSettingView) },
                  { typeof (SettingsViewModel), typeof(SettingsView) },
                  { typeof (SearchResultDialogViewModel), typeof(SearchResultDialogView) },
            };

            var container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
            container.AddAll(viewModelViewLookup);      
        }
```

With this, my application no longer goes past the MvvmCross logo screen.

Alternately, I tried providing the concrete view model type within FloatSettingView.cs as follows:

```
[Activity(Label = "settings", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class FloatSettingView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FloatSettingView);
        }

        public new FloatSettingViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return base.ViewModel as FloatSettingViewModel; }
            set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        }
    }
```

Using only this second approach, without providing a view model to view type mapping in Setup.cs, I get an exception when the framework attempts to load FloatSettingView.  Exception is  `Failed to find viewmodel for Pidac.Core.ViewModels.FloatSettingViewModel.`

I tried the third option of decorating my view with the MvxViewForAttribute as follows:

```
 [Activity(Label = "settings", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
[MvxViewFor(typeof(FloatSettingViewModel))]
        public class FloatSettingView : MvxActivity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FloatSettingView);
            } 

        }
```

with no luck.  I am obviously overlooking something here. Before I dig into the source, has anyone done this before?

TIA.

Comment: 'Failed to find viewmodel' suggests the problem is with the view model lookup - is your app.cs in the same assembly as your view models? If not, try overriding GetVirwModelAssemblies in Setup. Stuart (away from home on mobile - so no proper answers)

Comment: Stuart, that was it thanks.  App.cs is not in the same assemblies as some of these ViewModels. Overriding GetViewModelAssemblies in Setup is all I had to do.  Did not need any of the aforementioned.  Thanks again.

Comment: Can you explain how you overrode `GetViewModelAssemblies`?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, GetViewModelAssemblies is a protected virtual method defined in MvxSetup.  Override this in the Setup class defined in Setup.cs found in the root of the corresponding platform's project.  For  Android, Setup.cs derives from MvxAndroidDialogSetup.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `base.InitializeViewLookup()` when overriding, so you can get past the splash screen.